# FakeItEasy - Is it possible to intercept a method and replace it with my own implementation?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, fakeiteasy

I have the following interface :

```
public interface IOuputDestination
{
    void Write(String s);
}
```

In my unit test, I mock it like so :

```
var outputDestination = A.Fake<IOutputDestination>();
```

What I want to do, is intercept the Write method so that it uses my custom implementation that I define in my test. Something like this :

```
String output = "";
A.CallTo(() => outputDestination.Write(A<String>.Ignored)).Action(s => output += s);
              //Is something like this even possible ? ----^
```

Here the `Action` method does not exist, but what I would like to happen is that any parameter passed into `outputDestination.Write` be redirected to my custom action. Is this possible using FakeItEasy? If not, is there another mocking framework that allows this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get that behavior with `Invokes`:

```
String output = "";
A.CallTo(() => outputDestination.Write(A<String>.Ignored))
    .Invokes((string s) => output += s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really show how you're using `outputDestination` once you've created it. Would you be injecting it into some method under test? If so, then What if, instead of creating a fake, you create a specially crafted class that implements `IOutputDestination` and which contains your required implementation of `Write()`?

I guess this would depend what (if any) other bahaviours you need to verify on your fake. Its hard to know without more context.